# ListView remember only the position of old list after Filtering

Tags: android, listview, filtering

i created an app that show a listview with clickable items. i have an edit text to make the search. everything is working great but when im searching for an item, the app give my a new list, the probleme is when im clicking on any item on thisnew list items it redirect me to the link of the item in old list.here is my code: 
-For ReaderListAdapter.java :

```
  import java.util.List;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.view.animation.Animation;
  import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
  import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

 public class ReaderListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private List<Reader> listReader = null;
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
 Context context;
 private int lastPosition = -1;

// constructeur
public ReaderListAdapter(Context context, List<Reader> listFood) {
this.listReader = listFood;
layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
this.listReader = listFood;
this.context = context;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return listReader.size();
}

 @Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return listReader.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return arg0;
}

static class ViewHolder {
TextView nomView;
TextView priceView;
ImageView pictureView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reader_row, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    // initialisation des vues
    holder.nomView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.priceView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    holder.pictureView = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.picture);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
// affchier les données convenablement dans leurs positions
holder.nomView.setText(listReader.get(position).getName());
holder.priceView.setText(String.valueOf(listReader.get(position)
        .getPrice()));
       holder.pictureView.setBackgroundDrawable(listReader.get(position).getPicture());

// changer R.anim.ton_effet
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
        (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                : R.anim.up_from_bottom);

convertView.startAnimation(animation);
lastPosition = position;
return convertView;
}}
```

For MainActivity.java

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ListView;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  String[] listNames = { "site1", "site2", "site3"};
  int[] listPrices = { 1, 2, 3};
  ArrayList<Reader> listReader;
  ListView lv;
  EditText search;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listReader);
search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
Drawable[] listPictures = {
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a1),
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a2),
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a3)};

listReader = new ArrayList<Reader>();

for (int i = 0; i < listPictures.length; i++) {
    listReader.add(new Reader(i + 1, listNames[i], listPictures[i],
            listPrices[i]));
}

lv.setAdapter(new ReaderListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listReader));
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
            int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        filtrer();
    } });

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebActivity.class);

        switch (position) {
        case 0:                
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")) ;break;

        case 1:
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com")) ;break;

        case 2:
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.quranf.com")) ;break;
      }
        if (intent != null) {
              startActivity(intent);
            }} });}

 public void filtrer() {
// retourner la chaine saisie par l'utilisateur
String name = search.getText().toString();

// créer une nouvelle liste qui va contenir la résultat à afficher
final ArrayList<Reader> listReaderNew = new ArrayList<Reader>();

for (Reader reader : listReader) {
    // si le nom du food commence par la chaine saisie , ajouter-le !
    if (reader.getName().toLowerCase().toString().contains(name)) {
        listReaderNew.add(reader);
    }
}
// vider la liste
lv.setAdapter(null);
if (listReaderNew.size() == 0) {
    listReaderNew.add(new Reader(100, "Pas d'élements.. réessayer !",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.error), 0));
}
// ajouter la nouvelle liste
lv.setAdapter(new ReaderListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),    listReaderNew));
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated from you. thank you If you need any clarification plz let me know

Comment: i edit your code ...check this one...

Comment: yess...if your model class Reader doesn't have getName() method i.e. if you don't create getter and setter for name then filter according to your values which you set in your model class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class ReaderListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private List<Reader> listReader = null;
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
 Context context;
private int lastPosition = -1;
  ArrayList<Reader> arrayList;

// constructeur
public ReaderListAdapter(Context context, List<Reader> listFood) {
this.listReader = listFood;
layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
this.listReader = listFood;
this.context = context;
this.arrayList=listFood;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return listReader.size();
}

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return listReader.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return arg0;
  }

 static class ViewHolder {
 TextView nomView;
 TextView priceView;
 ImageView pictureView;
 }

  @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ViewHolder holder;

if (convertView == null) {
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reader_row, null);
holder = new ViewHolder();
// initialisation des vues
holder.nomView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
holder.priceView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
holder.pictureView = (ImageView) convertView
        .findViewById(R.id.picture);

convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
// affchier les données convenablement dans leurs positions
 holder.nomView.setText(listReader.get(position).getName());
 holder.priceView.setText(String.valueOf(listReader.get(position)
    .getPrice()));
           holder.pictureView.setBackgroundDrawable(listReader.get(position).getPicture());

// changer R.anim.ton_effet
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
    (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
            : R.anim.up_from_bottom);

convertView.startAnimation(animation);
lastPosition = position;
return convertView;
}
public void filter(String charText) {
charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
listFood.clear();
if (charText.length() == 0) {
    listFood.addAll(arraylist);
} else {
    for (Reader cp : arraylist) {
        if (cp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                .contains(charText)) {
            listFood.add(cp);
        }
    }
}
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

*******************your MainActivity**********************

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  String[] listNames = { "site1", "site2", "site3"};
  int[] listPrices = { 1, 2, 3};
  ArrayList<Reader> listReader;
  ListView lv;
  EditText search;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listReader);
 search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
  Drawable[] listPictures = {
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a1),
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a2),
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a3)};

  listReader = new ArrayList<Reader>();

 for (int i = 0; i < listPictures.length; i++) {
listReader.add(new Reader(i + 1, listNames[i], listPictures[i],
        listPrices[i]));
 }
 ReaderListAdapter readerListAdapternew ReaderListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listReader)
 lv.setAdapter(readerListAdapternew);
 search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

 search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
    int arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
    int arg2, int arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
  String text = search.getText().toString()
                .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        readerListAdapternew .filter(text);
 } });


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
 {
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebActivity.class);

    switch (position) {
    case 0:                
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")) ;break;

    case 1:
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com")) ;break;

    case 2:
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.quranf.com")) ;break;
  }
    if (intent != null) {
          startActivity(intent);
        }} });}
  }
```

Comment: Hey, now my code is not working. my old code work perfectly only dont give me the right item after filtering